# How make something fixed position during scroll in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm up to making a screen like on the pic

[image]

I'd like to add scroll for gridview, but the trouble now is I don't really understand how to achieve that.
When I wrap Grid with SingleChildGridView, I've got an error that bottom overflowed. Example is on the second screen:

[image]

Obviously, it's happening as the GridView is a part of Column which causes the error. But how can I find a wayaround to avoid wrapping the column with let's say singlechildscrollview  and at the same time making scrollable only GridView ?
Here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: HomeAppBar(),
  bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavBar(),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
       
        Text(
          'Hemendra',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
          child: Text(
            'Welcome to Laza.',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium
          ),
        ),
        Searchbox(),
        BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is ProductLoaded) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    
                              
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate:
                         SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          
                    mainAxisExtent: 300,
                     crossAxisCount: 2,
                  
                    ),
                    itemCount: state.products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  BlocProvider.of<ProductDetailsBloc>(
                                          context)
                                      .add(ProductDetailsEvent(
                                          state.products[index]));
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context, '/product_details');
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 240,
                                  
                                  child: Image.network(
                                  
                                      state.products[index].imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    icon: Image(
                                      image: AssetImage('heart.png'),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        state.products[index].name,
                                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    "\$" +
                                        state.products[index].price
                                            .toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: HexColor('1D1E20'),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ))
                            ],
                          ),
                          
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

Comment: are you trying to put those brand row on top as fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `SingleChildScrollView` and warp you `BlocBuilder` with Expanded widget .
so you code widget inside Scaffold body like this

```
Column(
    children: [
        searchBox(),
        SizedBox(height:70, child: horizontalBrandList()), 
        Expanded(child: BlocBuilder(...))
    ],
)
```

> created code similar UI code for better understanding update your code accordingly:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      //SEARCH BAR 
      const TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Search")),
      const SizedBox(height: 12),
      // HORIZONTAL LIST VIEW
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: List.generate(
            10,
            (i) => Container(
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.accents[i % 16],
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('$i'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 12),
      // GRID LISTVIEW
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            childAspectRatio: 0.8,
            crossAxisSpacing: 8,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          ),
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

You are adding `ListView` inside `Column` so You need to wrap with with Expanded `Widget`. in ListView contains own `ScrollController` so **no need to wrap** it with external `SingleChildScrollView`